# Search function does not work in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is Most important thing to change without this search function does not work

*Without this they does not find the string that you will search*

And show Like this in your url `localhost:7276/HomePage/Index?`

First i use this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
```

Second i use this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
```

```
<form method="get" action="/HomePage/Index" class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
  <div class="input-group sty">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your previous question, it seems that you are trying to
implement a search option at your nav bar. So you were missing this
two properties in your view.  `name="SearchString"`
`value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"`.

**How It works**

When you submit the below `form` it will `submit` your user search
input which has been set to `SearchString` as `name` property. So at
your controller you will receive the value for `string searchString`
which will filter your search result and return the new view

```
<form method="get" action="/Home/Index">     
  <td style="padding-right:760px">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </td>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    members = members.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString) || m.Gender.Contains(searchString));

    return View(members);
}
```

**Note:** Above submitted keys `name="SearchString"` will be passed there and return the new view with the matched search key value result.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You were telling about `[authorize]` we can use something else instead of using `[authorize]`

Comment: No `[authorize]` is perfectly fine. I asked to comment that for development testing purposes as it always inforse you to log in. What we practice in our daily development work is to stop the authentication steps while working on coding to save few minutes

Comment: okok one  more question like when we create any model we give id to that model and then we migrate  but question is how migration is know about id is a primary key

Comment: Ha ha its a long descriptive questions Gaurav,  if you look into your project reference there is entity framework dll you would see where there is a bundle of command to let the complier known how to mapped poco object to database entity.